# Progress Bar gets stuck converting Lines to Polygons using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, linestring, geometry-conversion

I'm trying to convert lines to polygon using QGIS 2.8.1.

I use `Vector > Geometry Tools > Polygons to Lines`.

I always get the progress bar stuck on 90%, it can't get to 100%.

[image]

Could someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi Shinoda, have you given it enough time after it freezes? You can check your **Task Manager** (right-click the Window's toolbar), select the _Processes_ tab and look for `qgis-bin.exe`. If the CPU has a value > 0 then it's probably still processing the data. This happens to me quite often.